# How to display all the registered profiles in a wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am told to make a wordpress site where i will be having a registration form.. Once the registration is done. The person will be logging in. And on one page say 'collogues', the logged in person will be able to see all the other registered people's photo and their names. And if he opens that photo, the profile will appear. (Profile details taken while registration).

Just like a social media but no friend request, no comments nothing else. Not even algos to match the gender.
Simple login and you will be able to see other people's profile pages and probably edit your profile every now and then....

Answer (score 0):

Your task seems simple. You may use [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) plugin to build login system and then upon logging users in you can fetch all users from `wp_users` table and link their profile to single.php, where its displays all user data.